Clicked "Payment by credit card..." on SB16; paid on the website; PTO-2038
I submitted and paid the fees for a Provisional Patent Application.
The application consisted of the following document: (web) ADS, PTO/SB/16, PTO/SB/15A, the specification, drawings, an abstract, and claims.
On PTO/SB/16, there's a checkbox that reads:

Payment by credit card. Form PTO-2038 is attached.

I clicked it.
Later I paid the fee on the USPTO website directly, by credit card, but I never submitted PTO-2038.
Could this be a problem, and, if so, how can it be fixed?

Do you have a customer number?

I think I don't. I do have an Application #, Confirmation #, Patent Center #, and Payment Transaction ID.

Without a customer number you can file on-line but can’t see what you filed until and unless your application is published.
You can call the inventor assistance line. See https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/inventors-assistance-center-iac

Thank you. They should know what to do.
